# open GL game (cubes)

Tags: ios, opengl-es, game-development

I am new to open gl game side of Xcode. i have just been playing with the cubes and have managed to rotate them etc. but there were couple of things i had in my mind that i wanted to achieve but due to my lack of knowledge i just couldn't. for instance i wanted to change the cubes to say tetrahedrons or add different colour to each side of the cubes or maybe even add  third cube as the default code only supplies us with just 2 cubes.

view controller.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <GLKit/GLKit.h>

@interface ViewController : GLKViewController

@end
```

view controller.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

#define BUFFER_OFFSET(i) ((char *)NULL + (i))

// Uniform index.
enum
{
    UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX,
    UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX,
    NUM_UNIFORMS
};
GLint uniforms[NUM_UNIFORMS];

// Attribute index.
enum
{
    ATTRIB_VERTEX,
    ATTRIB_NORMAL,
    NUM_ATTRIBUTES
};

GLfloat gCubeVertexData[216] = 
{
    // Data layout for each line below is:
    // positionX, positionY, positionZ,     normalX, normalY, normalZ,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,          1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,         0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,          0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,          0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,       -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,       -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,        -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f,

    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,       0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f,

    0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,          0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, 0.5f,        0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f,

    0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,       0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,         0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    -0.5f, -0.5f, -0.5f,       0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f,
    -0.5f, 0.5f, -0.5f,        0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f
};

@interface ViewController () {
    GLuint _program;

    GLKMatrix4 _modelViewProjectionMatrix;
    GLKMatrix3 _normalMatrix;
    float _rotation;

    GLuint _vertexArray;
    GLuint _vertexBuffer;
}
@property (strong, nonatomic) EAGLContext *context;
@property (strong, nonatomic) GLKBaseEffect *effect;

- (void)setupGL;
- (void)tearDownGL;

- (BOOL)loadShaders;
- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type file:(NSString *)file;
- (BOOL)linkProgram:(GLuint)prog;
- (BOOL)validateProgram:(GLuint)prog;
@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    self.context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];

    if (!self.context) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to create ES context");
    }

    GLKView *view = (GLKView *)self.view;
    view.context = self.context;
    view.drawableDepthFormat = GLKViewDrawableDepthFormat24;

    [self setupGL];
}

- (void)dealloc
{    
    [self tearDownGL];

    if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == self.context) {
        [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
    }
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

    if ([self isViewLoaded] && ([[self view] window] == nil)) {
        self.view = nil;

        [self tearDownGL];

        if ([EAGLContext currentContext] == self.context) {
            [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:nil];
        }
        self.context = nil;
    }

    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (void)setupGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    [self loadShaders];

    self.effect = [[GLKBaseEffect alloc] init];
    self.effect.light0.enabled = GL_TRUE;
    self.effect.light0.diffuseColor = GLKVector4Make(1.0f, 0.4f, 0.4f, 1.0f);

    glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);

    glGenVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);
    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    glGenBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, _vertexBuffer);
    glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(gCubeVertexData), gCubeVertexData, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribPosition);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribPosition, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(0));
    glEnableVertexAttribArray(GLKVertexAttribNormal);
    glVertexAttribPointer(GLKVertexAttribNormal, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(12));

    glBindVertexArrayOES(0);
}

- (void)tearDownGL
{
    [EAGLContext setCurrentContext:self.context];

    glDeleteBuffers(1, &_vertexBuffer);
    glDeleteVertexArraysOES(1, &_vertexArray);

    self.effect = nil;

    if (_program) {
        glDeleteProgram(_program);
        _program = 0;
    }
}

#pragma mark - GLKView and GLKViewController delegate methods

- (void)update
{
    float aspect = fabsf(self.view.bounds.size.width / self.view.bounds.size.height);
    GLKMatrix4 projectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakePerspective(GLKMathDegreesToRadians(65.0f), aspect, 0.1f, 100.0f);

    self.effect.transform.projectionMatrix = projectionMatrix;

    GLKMatrix4 baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -4.0f);
    baseModelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(baseModelViewMatrix, _rotation, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);

    // Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with GLKit
    GLKMatrix4 modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.5f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, _rotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

    self.effect.transform.modelviewMatrix = modelViewMatrix;

    // Compute the model view matrix for the object rendered with ES2
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4MakeTranslation(0.0f, 0.0f, 1.5f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Rotate(modelViewMatrix, _rotation, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    modelViewMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(baseModelViewMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

    _normalMatrix = GLKMatrix3InvertAndTranspose(GLKMatrix4GetMatrix3(modelViewMatrix), NULL);

    _modelViewProjectionMatrix = GLKMatrix4Multiply(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix);

    _rotation += self.timeSinceLastUpdate * 0.5f;
}

- (void)glkView:(GLKView *)view drawInRect:(CGRect)rect
{
    glClearColor(0.65f, 0.65f, 0.65f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glBindVertexArrayOES(_vertexArray);

    // Render the object with GLKit
    [self.effect prepareToDraw];

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);

    // Render the object again with ES2
    glUseProgram(_program);

    glUniformMatrix4fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX], 1, 0,   _modelViewProjectionMatrix.m);
    glUniformMatrix3fv(uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX], 1, 0, _normalMatrix.m);

    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 36);
}

#pragma mark -  OpenGL ES 2 shader compilation

- (BOOL)loadShaders
{
    GLuint vertShader, fragShader;
    NSString *vertShaderPathname, *fragShaderPathname;

    // Create shader program.
    _program = glCreateProgram();

    // Create and compile vertex shader.
    vertShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"vsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&vertShader type:GL_VERTEX_SHADER file:vertShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Create and compile fragment shader.
    fragShaderPathname = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Shader" ofType:@"fsh"];
    if (![self compileShader:&fragShader type:GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER file:fragShaderPathname]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to compile fragment shader");
        return NO;
    }

    // Attach vertex shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, vertShader);

    // Attach fragment shader to program.
    glAttachShader(_program, fragShader);

    // Bind attribute locations.
    // This needs to be done prior to linking.
    glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribPosition, "position");
    glBindAttribLocation(_program, GLKVertexAttribNormal, "normal");

    // Link program.
    if (![self linkProgram:_program]) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to link program: %d", _program);

        if (vertShader) {
            glDeleteShader(vertShader);
            vertShader = 0;
        }
        if (fragShader) {
            glDeleteShader(fragShader);
            fragShader = 0;
        }
        if (_program) {
            glDeleteProgram(_program);
            _program = 0;
        }

        return NO;
    }

    // Get uniform locations.
    uniforms[UNIFORM_MODELVIEWPROJECTION_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "modelViewProjectionMatrix");
    uniforms[UNIFORM_NORMAL_MATRIX] = glGetUniformLocation(_program, "normalMatrix");

    // Release vertex and fragment shaders.
    if (vertShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, vertShader);
        glDeleteShader(vertShader);
    }
    if (fragShader) {
        glDetachShader(_program, fragShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragShader);
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)compileShader:(GLuint *)shader type:(GLenum)type file:(NSString *)file
{
    GLint status;
    const GLchar *source;

    source = (GLchar *)[[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:file encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil] UTF8String];
    if (!source) {
        NSLog(@"Failed to load vertex shader");
        return NO;
    }

    *shader = glCreateShader(type);
    glShaderSource(*shader, 1, &source, NULL);
    glCompileShader(*shader);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetShaderInfoLog(*shader, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Shader compile log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetShaderiv(*shader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        glDeleteShader(*shader);
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)linkProgram:(GLuint)prog
{
    GLint status;
    glLinkProgram(prog);

#if defined(DEBUG)
    GLint logLength;
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program link log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }
#endif

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_LINK_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)validateProgram:(GLuint)prog
{
    GLint logLength, status;

    glValidateProgram(prog);
    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_INFO_LOG_LENGTH, &logLength);
    if (logLength > 0) {
        GLchar *log = (GLchar *)malloc(logLength);
        glGetProgramInfoLog(prog, logLength, &logLength, log);
        NSLog(@"Program validate log:\n%s", log);
        free(log);
    }

    glGetProgramiv(prog, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, &status);
    if (status == 0) {
        return NO;
    }

    return YES;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 0):

Listing your requests:

**Face Color:**

According to the code you have reported, it does not support vertex colors attributes. In fact, the vertex array you build covers vertex position and normals, colors are not covered (positionX, positionY, positionZ,     normalX, normalY, normalZ)

Eventually, to support colors you should do something like:

positionX, positionY, positionZ,     normalX, normalY, normalZ, red, green, blue

This would set up the data information required for colors.

About "rendering" the color, your fragment shaders would need to be modified and the colors passed as additional attribute.

You didn't include the shader source code, would be nice to see it to better understand.

About passing the additional attribute you could do something like this:

glEnableVertexAttribArray(ID of the attrubute);
glVertexAttribPointer(ID of the attrubute, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 24, BUFFER_OFFSET(36));

**About tetrahedrons:**

it is fairly simple to calculate the coordinate of the different vertices.

In the end you have 4 triangles and to calculate the 12 vertices (5 in common) is a good exercise that would take 5 minutes on paper. I suggest you to try it and see. It is a very good practice to try :)